# how to create 1 array from 2 arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

**I have 2 array:**

a = [23,24,25]

b = [1990/23, 1997/23, 1998/24, 2001/25, 2002/25, 2003/25]

**I hope result:**

=> c = [ 23:[1990, 1997], 24:[1998],25:[2001, 2002, 2003]]

Comment: `1990/23` should be a string

Comment: First off, SO is not a place where people code for you. But to help, you need to use a nested `for loop` with `a` being the first loop and `b` being the second. Then you use sub string to see if one of the values of `a` is in the value of `b` and create a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

```js
const a = [23, 24, 25];
const b = [`1990/23`, `1997/23`, `1998/24`, `2001/25`, `2002/25`, `2003/25`];

const c = b.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [year, date] = curr.split("/");
  (acc[date] ??= []).push(year);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(c);
```

If you want to grab only the object with the key in `a` and return the empty `[]` if object is not there in `b`.

```js
const a = [23, 24, 25, 26, 27];
const b = [`1990/23`, `1997/23`, `1998/24`, `2001/25`, `2002/25`, `2003/25`];

const dict = b.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [year, date] = curr.split("/");
  (acc[date] ??= []).push(year);
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = {};
for (let key of a) {
  result[key] = dict[key] ?? [];
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

c should be an object, not an array and the values in b should be string so that you can

```
const c = {}
for(let str of b) {
   const splitted = str.split('/')
   if(a.includes(splitted[1])) { // Check if the value is in the array a
       if(c[splitted[1]]) { // Just push in the array if it already exists
          c[splitted[1]].push(splitted[0])
       } else { // create new array 
          c[splitted[1]] = [splitted[0]]
       }
   }
}
```